# PHP PDO left join tables where fields don't match

Tags: php, sql, join, pdo, left-join

I'm building a quiz for a client that wants their quiz results to auto saved and I've run into a problem, I'm trying to select all the questions that the user hasn't answered in a certain quiz, I'm saving the result of each question that's been answered to a table `RESULTS` but my statement is messing up when more then one user has results in the `RESULTS` table, if anyone could have a look at my code and give me any advice it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Based off of these tables and the statement the next question that I need to load is `que_id = 3` for `use_id = 1` but the problem I'm facing is that it returns `que_id = 1` and `que_id = 3` because they're were answered by the users `use_id = 2` and `use_id 3`, thanks again!

**QUESTIONS TABLE**

```
que_id qui_id que_question que_ans_id
1      1      lorem 1?     1
2      1      lorem 2?     6
3      1      lorem 3?     12
```

**RESULTS TABLE**

```
res_id res_use_id res_qui_id res_que_id res_ans_id
1      1          1          1          2
2      1          1          2          6
3      2          1          3          10
4      3          1          1          1
```

**PHP**

```
$statement_question = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM roa_quiz
                                    LEFT JOIN roa_questions ON qui_id = que_qui_id
                                    LEFT JOIN roa_results ON que_id = res_que_id
                                    WHERE qui_id = :qui_id AND res_use_id != :use_id");

$statement_question->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$statement_question->execute(array(':qui_id' => 1, ':use_id' => 1));

$question = $statement_question->fetch();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get rows that do *not* match.  The idea is to use `left outer join` to get matching rows . . . and then check where there are no matches.  This requires two things:  (1) moving the conditions to the `on` clause and (2) check for no match in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM roa_quiz LEFT JOIN
     roa_questions
     ON qui_id = que_qui_id LEFT JOIN
     roa_results
     ON que_id = res_que_id and res_use_id = :use_id
where qui_id = :qui_id AND results.res_que_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM roa_quiz
JOIN roa_questions ON qui_id = que_qui_id
LEFT JOIN roa_results ON que_id = res_que_id AND res_use_id = :use_id
WHERE qui_id = :qui_id
AND res_id IS NULL
```

That should get you a list of unanswered questions for a user for a quiz. [Have a look here for some useful diagrams on sql joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). In this case we need a left outer join, with an exclude.